# How much give is allowed with existing copper pipe?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, copper-pipe

In my bathroom remodel adventure, I'm installing a Delta 500 Shower surround which is a direct-to-stud install.

I'm in the dry fitting stage, and everything is going well. When dry fitting the wet wall, I realized the control valve needs to move back about 3/4" to 1". The reason is that this wall was previously tiled, so with the tile and backer board gone, the value is protruding too far.

I cut the notch in the stud which was previously there about another 3/8" deep so the valve can move back as shown with the red arrow in the following picture:

[image]

The question is: how much flex is allowed in an install like this? I *can* push the valve back (and needed slightly to the right, maybe 1/8") without a whole lot of effort, but is this too much stress on the copper? Or do I need to cut the copper and I'm thinking a couple of 45* to offset it back a bit would do the trick.

Edit: I did the math and having back to back 45s create an offset of 1.4", which is too much, so if I do need to cut this, it looks like I'd have to bend a piece of copper myself the required amount and couple it in. Not a big deal, but if I can avoid it, it would be nice.

I made a quick video for you to see how much the value needs to move:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/vLzkzoDowPz5NXrEA

Comment: Will it need to be more of bend right there, or can the pipes be moved back from the holes in the floors.  A bend there might be too much for the joints, but if the whole line can move back it might be okay.  Just bend/flex/angle the line from near the floor.

Comment: More of a bend right where? It doesn't matter to me where the bend comes from. The whole line is moving back from the floor on up. There's no room for the pipe to move through the floor however, as the holes which were drilled are a pretty tight fit.

Comment: Long pipes can take an angle better than bending a short section, so if top pipes can be push back also, not so bad.  If not, would with the 45s or a section/s of pex.

Comment: The section from the valve to the floor is 42" which is the length in which would be available to offset the whole valve.  I'm not sure what short section you're referring to? Take a look at the link to the video to see what I mean.

Comment: Trying to just push that valve in more without the top pipes being in more, might be too much stress, but the top of pipes might be in too far.

Comment: The top pipe isn't a concern, it's just the shower head, which is easily moved.